# ERROR: "invalid input syntax for type DATE" while importing data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

I am importing data in PostgreSQL database from .LOD files(which contains data in csv format). For importing I am following these steps:

1) Right Click On table name

2) click on import

3) select file from which data has to be imported

4) done

But while doing this I am getting an error message for a table with data like:

```
APP_PGM_APPLY,APP_PGM_CS_NUM,APP_PGM_REQ_DT,APP_PGM_STS,APP_PGM_STS_DT,CR_TS_HI,CR_TS_LO,EFF_BEG_DT,EFF_END_DT,VOID_SW,APP_PGM_NUM
"RE","TD877E3","20150105","DN","20150105","   362952774","   304895920","20150105",          ,   ,"2H01889"                       
"RE","B1ZBA17","20150130","PE","20150130","   363222251","   178702340","20150130","20150204",   ,"2I15600"
```

The error message is:

[image]

both date fields are allowed to accept null values. But still it is throwing this error.
Table defination:

```
CREATE TABLE app_pgm_choice
(
  app_pgm_apply character(2),
  app_pgm_cs_num character(7),
  app_pgm_req_dt date,
  app_pgm_sts character(2),
  app_pgm_sts_dt date,
  cr_ts_hi integer NOT NULL,
  cr_ts_lo integer NOT NULL,
  eff_beg_dt date,
  eff_end_dt date,
  void_sw character(1),
  app_pgm_num character(7) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT app_pgm_choice_pk1 PRIMARY KEY (app_pgm_num, cr_ts_hi, cr_ts_lo)
)
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What is the data format of the column in that table ?? or just show the table structure in the question

Comment: I added table defination in my post

Comment: A guess : the suspect will be the null values here `304895920","20150105",          ,   ,"2H01889"  `

Comment: yeah the null values at this position are giving error. But why? My table should accept null values

Answer (score 1):

Try copy using this

```
copy tablename from 'd:/folder/myfile.csv' delimiter ',' csv WITH NULL AS 'null';
```

I dint  import a `.lod` file but you can try above script by replacing  `'d:/folder/myfile.csv'` with `'d:/folder/myfile.lod'` or renaming your `.lod` file to `.csv`

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for long time I got the solution. I changed my .LOD file content in the following manner (replaced date column data '    ' with '' OR I can say I removed white spaces for date column)

```
APP_PGM_APPLY,APP_PGM_CS_NUM,APP_PGM_REQ_DT,APP_PGM_STS,APP_PGM_STS_DT,CR_TS_HI,CR_TS_LO,EFF_BEG_DT,EFF_END_DT,VOID_SW,APP_PGM_NUM
"RE","TD877E3","20150105","DN","20150105","   362952774","   304895920","20150105",,   ,"2H01889"                       
"RE","B1ZBA17","20150130","PE","20150130","   363222251","   178702340","20150130","20150204",   ,"2I15600"
```

And I run the following command:

```
COPY app_pgm_choice FROM 'E:\Japser\Jasper Reports\Data\APP_PGM_CHOICE.LOD' CSV HEADER;
```

Its working fine :)